# Understanding Continuity of Functions

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, limits, continuity, intuition

I know that graphically a function $f(x)$ is said to be continuous in $[a,b]$ if there are no breaks in the curve for $f(x)$ in the interval $[a,b]$

I also know that by definition, a function $f(x)$ is said to be continuous at any given point $a$ if, we can find a $\delta>0$, for a given $\epsilon>0$ such that,
the distance  between $f(x)$ and $f(a)$ is less that $\epsilon$ whenever, the distance between $x$ and $a$ is less that $\delta$

But the problem is i am not able to "visualize" or "see" from the definition how it implies that the curve has no breaks. Some illustrations will be helpful

Thanks

Comment: Think "close in domain implies close in range". That is how my calculus professor helped me visualize the delta-epsilon definition.

Comment: ok but how does distances correspond to the idea of no breaks ? or i am approaching it totally in the wrong way ?

Comment: Well, what does a break look like?  A non-trivial change in the $y$-direction with essentially no change in the $x$ direction.

Comment: [This](https://www.math.ucdavis.edu/~kouba/CalcOneDIRECTORY/preciselimdirectory/PreciseLimit.html) is the picture my professor drew that really made it click for me. Now picture a jump discontinuity and convince yourself that you could not draw such bounds.

Answer (score 2):

A more helpful definition of continuity is the one given by Cauchy in 1821, in his work Cours d'Analyse.  Cauchy said that a function $y=f(x)$ is continuous between two bounds if for all $x$ between those bounds, an infinitesimal $x$-increment necessarily produces an infinitesimal change in $y$; in other words, the value of $y$ can't "jump" and therefore there are no "breaks" in the curve.

A more detailed discussion of indivisibles and infinitesimals in the work of Fermat, Leibniz, Euler, and Cauchy may be found in [this text](http://arxiv.org/abs/1306.5973).

Answer (score 0):

Consider the step function,
$$f(x) =  \left\{ \begin{array}{ll}
  0, & x \leq 0 \\
  1, & x > 0 \end{array}\right.
$$
$f$ has a "break" at $x=0$.  Observe that $f(0) = 0$.  Now suppose $\epsilon = 1/2$ (really, any $\epsilon < 1$ is sufficient).  Is there any possible value $\delta > 0$ that guarantees that if $|x - 0| < \delta$, then $|f(x) - 0| < 1/2$?  What if the chosen $x$ is positive?